# ServletDispatcher пропускает папку

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, tomee

Почему когда я пытаюсь перенаправить сервлет на страницу он пропускает папку /jsp и ищет login.jsp в корневой папке?

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Получаю 404:

```
Type Status Report

Message /login.jsp
```

Сервлет:

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginCtrl extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

jsp лежит в:

```
src/main/webapp/jsp/login.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в фильтре. Это он перенаправлял на login.jsp, потому что я забыл изменить путь так же в фильтре.